# Imagick output false image

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

this page script have at bottom,

> imagick classes   Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
>
> ImageMagick version    ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10 Q16

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

$im = new Imagick("/home/palirsin/public_html/imagick/ie9.png");

$im->thumbnailImage(200, null);

$im->borderImage(new ImagickPixel("white"), 5, 5);

$reflection = $im->clone();
$reflection->flipImage();

$gradient = new Imagick();

$gradient->newPseudoImage($reflection->getImageWidth() + 10,$reflection->getImageHeight() + 10, "gradient:transparent-black");

$reflection->compositeImage($gradient, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

$reflection->setImageOpacity( 0.3 );

$canvas = new Imagick();

$width = $im->getImageWidth() + 40;
$height = ($im->getImageHeight() * 2) + 30;
$canvas->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel("black"));
$canvas->setImageFormat("png");

$canvas->compositeImage($im, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 20, 10);
$canvas->compositeImage($reflection, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,20, $im->getImageHeight() + 10);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
```

Script giving this picture
https://www.alirsin.com/imagick/info.php

But **true** picture is bottom
http://www.irfansahin.com/imagick/info.php

What is wrong at script.

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php instead. You're not echoing out your image, you're echoing out the imagick object. I don't see anywhere in the docs that imagick implements __toString()

Comment: I was echoing but working I can see image.

Comment: @MarcB I added that doc this week - it should show up this weeks on the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and give a result similar to what you are expecting on my machine, which means that it is almost certainly an issue with using a buggy version of ImageMagick that is causing your problem.

The ImageMagick version 6.5.4-7 was released on [2009-07-30](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) which is rather ancient in terms of bugfixes. I'd strongly recommend to the latest version of ImageMagick that you can, both to make your code work, and also for several security issues.